# posting a message with a picture in a Facebook Event

Tags: facebook, api, events, post, image

I tried firstly  with Graph API Explorer to add a post to an event (all the permissions are ok),
but when I post, only the message appear and not the picture.
The only parameters I use are message and picture, so I'm quite confused why it doesn't work in the term of posting only the message, just cause I follow this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: we need to have a look at your code , in order to comment